Definitions and intuition of regular representation of a group
I was studying representation theory when a question came to my mind.
I have come across two different definitions of regular representation of a group G:

the first one defines the regular left representation of a group G to be the map associating to each element of the group the permutation of the group's underlying set obtained by left multiplication by that element;
the second one defines a regular representation of a group to be the matrix representation obtained by restriction/corestriction of a ring homomorphism from CG to the ring of |G| x |G| matrices with complex coefficients.

I don't get the link between these two and what they could represent (pardon the pun). The first sounds rather concrete, whereas the second more general. How are they related? What idea do they convey?

Where is the second definition from? It's not correct (you can't just pick any old ring homomorphism).

@SteveD My professor's notes of representation theory. I suppose the morphism needs to be unitary in order to restrict and corestrict to a matrix representation, but up to this the definition seems clear. What I miss is the link with the first definition.

I don't understand what exactly is second definition, but I can tell you how the first definition can correspond to a matrix representation. Form a vector space with basis given by the underlying set of $G$. Action of any $g$ on this set can be linearly extended to linear transformation on the vector space. Now fix a basis and each $g$ corresponds to a $|G|\times|G|$ matrix. Different bases will give different matrix representations but they will all be isomorphic.

@TonyPizza Much appreciated. I was aware of that possibility but it is worth to point it out.

The definition is clear, sure, but it doesn't define a regular representation. You need more restrictions on the homomorphism.

@SteveD Is it right to say that every group determines only one entity of the first definition but possibly many of the second one? And, according to a previous comment, is the second definition a generalisation of the first one?

If you insist the homomorphism sends 1 to 1, then yes the second is a generalization of the first, since the first is the case the homomorphism is determined by the regular action (via an arbitrary numbering of the group elements), as Tony Pizza laid out above.
